# Reading clipboard specific format type in powershell?

Tags: powershell, clipboard

how can you read a specific (text/x-moz-url-priv) format type from the clipboard in powershell?

I have the following code:

```
cls
$clipboard = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetDataObject()
$clipboard.GetFormats()
```

if I copy text in the firefox browser then one of the formats is 'text/x-moz-url-priv'.
How can I read that?

The Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType command does not have that option